# Flink : DataStream to Table

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

**Usecase**: Read protobuf messages from Kafka, deserialize them, apply some transformation (flatten out some columns), and write to dynamodb.

Unfortunately, [Kafka Flink Connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/table/connect.html#kafka-connector) only supports - csv, json and avro formats. So, I had to use lower level APIs (datastream).

**Problem:** If I can create a table out of the datastream object, then I can accept a query to run on that table. It would make the transformation part seamless and generic. **Is it possible to run a SQL query over datastream object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have a `DataStream` of objects, then You can simply register given `DataStream` as Table using `StreamTableEnvironment`.

This would look more or less like below:

```
val myStream = ...
val env: StreamExecutionEnvironment = configureFlinkEnv(StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment)
val tEnv: StreamTableEnvironment = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
tEnv.registerDataStream("myTable", myStream, [Field expressions])
```

Then You should be able to query the dynamic table created from Your DataStream.